# Running thread when call a Flask Route

Tags: python, multithreading, api, flask

I'm doing an app using Flask plugin to create an API.

What I want is to run a function everytime this route is called (route is called with parameter id) but I don't want to launch multiple thread if the route is called many time with same id (if I call /route/1 twice, run thread only one time)

So for now, I do like this:

```
@app.route("/api/start/<remote_id>")
@limiter.limit("1 per second")
def start(remote_id):
        new_thread = threading.Thread(name=remote_id, target=run_detector,
                                           args=(remote_id)).start()

        return jsonify(True)
    else:
        return jsonify(False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

But the issue is when I call /api/start/1 it run the thread one time, but right after this call, I call /api/start/2, it will run 2 threads with same id (with only one call of Flask API ...), it's like the API is called twice but it's not the case (I add a print inside the @app.route and my print is displayed only one time)

Any idea to avoid this ?

Kind regards,
Florian.

Comment: What work is being carried out in the thread function?

Comment: A while True loop, that need to run a watchdog to check file changes in folder, and to run Opencv tasks on each images